# Laravel public folder show contents instead load index.php

Tags: laravel

I have created a laravel 5.5 project and I have already configured the apache DocumentRoot to the / var / www / html / (project) / public folder, when I access the site, instead of loading the index.php page, the files in the public folder are loaded.

My public / storage / bootstrap folder is with accesses 755 and chown apache: apache

PHP Version 7.1.27 - ok
Apache Running - ok

[when I access domain.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRfvA.png)

[when I click on index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YQ8A.png)

Comment: You need to add the PHP handler to your apache config.

Comment: you need to create virtual host for that

Comment: You're not running PHP on your HTTP server, it's serving a plain file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your HTTP server (Apache/Nginx) is not loading PHP FPM, so that's why it returns plain texts files, PHP is not being ran.

Don't forgot to update your HTTP config.